# bash: [: too many arguments?

Tags: bash, scripts, bashrc

I'm trying to create a directory and `cd` into it:

#### In ~/.bashrc:

```
function abc() {
  appname=$1
  appdir="$HOME/code/$appname"
  if [ mkdir $appdir -a cd $appdir ]; then
    echo Success
  else
    echo Failed to create and switch directory
  fi
}
```

When I reload bashrc (`. ~/.bashrc`) I get the error:

```
bash: [: too many arguments
Failed to create and switch directory
```

How do I fix this? And what does `[:` in the error mean?

**Ps.** Could someone direct me to a "non-cryptic" bash scripting tutorial?

Comment: There is something wrong in your script i guess,you can start by using proper syntax with if.  `if <COMMANDS>; then <COMMANDS>; fi`

Comment: I don't know if it's just me... but try Pitfall 6; I hear it gets a few people ;) http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main error in your script is that the `[` command, equivalent to `test` command, is used to test conditions, like string comparison, existence of files, and so on.

To test the exit status of processes you have to use `if` without `[`, so your script could be

```
if mkdir "$appdir" && cd "$appdir"; then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Failed to create and switch directory"
fi
```

This is explained in [Bash Pitfalls: 9. if [grep foo myfile](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D).

I suggest you go through [GrayCat Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) to understand bash.

Comment: That guide is really very good! Thank you, otherwise I would be still deciphering man pages :)

Comment: Another way is to check if the dir exists if [ -d "$APPDIR" ]; then
  cd $APPDIR
fi

Answer (score -3):

A prototype could be:

- Create a file in your desktop: `touch newDirectory.sh`
- Make file executable:  `chmod +x newDirectory.sh`
- To call the script from a terminal in the desktop :   `./newDirectory.sh anyName`

/

```
#!/bin/bash
function abc() {
  appname=${1}
  appdir="$HOME/Desktop/$appname"
  if (( mkdir "${appdir}" )) ; then     
    cd "${appdir}"  
    echo "Success" 
  else   
    echo "Failed to create and switch directory" 
  fi
}
abc ${1}
```

Little recommendation: if you are new, do not mess with `.bashrc` :)

Comment: Sorry, no. There are several problems with that answer. 1) missing a `{`. 2) it never runs `mkdir`. 3) you didn't test `cd`'s exit status. 4) Don't put extensions on scripts. Especially not `.sh` when it's not even an sh-script. 5) Putting it in a script defeats the purpose of the function. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Comment: @geirha: my fault, the `{` was there before my editing.

Comment: Answer: (( mkdir "${appdir}" ))  is equal `'`mkdir "${appdir}"`'` (look at the back ticks)

Comment: debug the script bash -x newDirectory.sh and you will see that the script will cd to the directory. If you want to run another process after that, It is a completely different horse.

Comment: The script run with bash dash ash. You can change the extension whatever you want.

Comment: Looks like you have read bash 4 specifications. (( mkdir "${appdir}" )) it is awesome , isn't

Comment: @studentz `(( mkdir "${appdir}" ))` will most likely give you a `division by 0` error. The part inside the double parenthesis is treated in arithmetic context, so it's trying to calculate gibberish. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression . The script will not work with dash or ash because defining a function using `function funcname() {` and the `((..))` syntax is bash-specific.

Comment: @geirha. Please read bash 4 specifications (()) not only apply to math. The script works perfectly run it

Comment: @studentz The manual does not concur with you. And running your little script gives errors, as expected: `./newdir: line 5: ((: mkdir /home/geirha/Desktop/test : division by 0 (error token is "/geirha/Desktop/test ")` followed by `Failed to create and switch directory`. Are you just trolling?